# Adding a new column to a data frame that turns non numerical values to binary ones using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binary, linear-regression

I have a data frame with a column “LN_status” where the values are either N1 or N0

I have to create a new column where I turn the response N1 to 1 and N0 to 0

I don’t know how to create a binary column with conditions that are not numerical.

If LN_status= N1, then the new column should say 1
If LN_status=N0, then the new column should say 0

I have to start with
new_df['LN']=
where new_df is my data frame and 'LN' is the name of the new column

Comment: `new_df['LN'] = new_df['LN_status'].eq('N1').astype(int)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataFrame.apply to create a series with the values you want, then add that series to new_df:

```
import pandas as pd
old_df = pd.DataFrame(["N0", "N1", "N0"], columns = ["LN_status"])
LN = old_df.apply(lambda row : int(row == "N1"), axis = 1)
new_df = old_df.copy()
new_df["LN"] = LN
```